# Prove that if the series is convergent then the law of large numbers hold.

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of pairwise independent random variables such that :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-1} P\left\{\max _{1 \leq m \leq n}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right)\right|>\varepsilon n\right\}<\infty$$

show that $n^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right) \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.

I'm fairly certain Borel Cantelli Lemma for pairwise independent random variables is to be used here but I dont know how to get rid of the $n^{-1}$ inside the series.

Comment: r u sure the $n^{-1}$ inside the series is supposed to be there?

Comment: @mathworker21 yes very sure.

Comment: Just curious, do you want to apply Borel Cantelli or why are you so focused on it?

Comment: @Diger this is part of paper I was reading, in the beginning the borel cantelli lemma is stated so I thought it had to be there for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote
$$
p_{n,\varepsilon}:= P\left\{\max _{1 \leqslant m \leqslant n}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right)\right|>\varepsilon n\right\}.
$$
If $2^N\leqslant n\leqslant 2^{N+1}-1$, then
$$
p_{2^N,2\varepsilon}\leqslant p_{n,\varepsilon}\leqslant  P\left\{\max _{1 \leqslant m \leqslant 2^{N+1}-1}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right)\right|>\varepsilon 2^N\right\}\leqslant p_{2^{N+1},\varepsilon/2}.
$$
Therefore, by splitting the series into a series of indexed between two consecutive dyadic numbers, one derives that the initial assumption is equivalent to $\sum_{N\geqslant 0}p_{2^N,\varepsilon}<+\infty$ for all $\varepsilon$. By an application of the Borel-Cantelli lemma, one derives that
$$
\frac 1{2^N}\max_{1\leqslant m\leqslant 2^N}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right)\right|\to 0\, a.s.
$$
from which it follows that $n^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right) \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.

Note that we do not use the pairwise independence of the sequence in this step; this is certainly needed in order to establish the convergence of the series given in the assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same notation as DG $$p_{n,\varepsilon}:= P\left\{\max _{1 \leq m \leq n} n^{-1} \left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right)\right|>\varepsilon \right\}$$ we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{p_{n,\epsilon}}{n}<\infty$$
for all $\epsilon>0$. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty$ it must also be true that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} p_{n,\epsilon} = 0$$
otherwise the series would diverge. This is equivalent to $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left\{\max _{1 \leq m \leq n} n^{-1} \left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right)\right|<\varepsilon \right\} = 1 $$ which is true $\forall \epsilon>0$. Therefore almost surely $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{-1} \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right)\right| \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \max _{1 \leq m \leq n} n^{-1} \left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right)\right|<\varepsilon$$
$\forall \epsilon>0$, which is what we need.

Comment: It seems that your penultimate equation would only give the convergence in probability to $0$, not the almost sure convergence. This is the best we can deduce from the fact that $p_{n,\varepsilon}\to 0$. For the almost sure convergence, one really has to exploit the convergence of the series.

Comment: What do you mean? $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left\{\max _{1 \leq m \leq n} n^{-1} \left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right)\right|<\varepsilon \right\} = 1$$ is not true?

Comment: I mean the equation you wrote in the comment is true, but that it only gives the convergence in probability.

Comment: Isn't that the same? With probability 1 (almost sure), we have that for $n\rightarrow \infty$ $$\max _{1 \leq m \leq n} n^{-1} \left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right)\right|<\varepsilon \, .$$

Comment: Put differently, is it not true that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left\{\max _{1 \leq m \leq n} n^{-1} \left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right)\right|<\varepsilon \right\} = P\left\{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\max _{1 \leq m \leq n} n^{-1} \left|\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(X_{k}-E X_{k}\right)\right|<\varepsilon \right\} \, ?$$

Comment: "For the almost sure convergence, one really has to exploit the convergence of the series." From the convergence of the series it follows $p_{n,\epsilon}=0$ in the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$. And if the latter identity holds, the rest should be a "trivial" deduction.

Comment: If we follow your reasoning, you deduce _from $p_{n,\varepsilon}\to 0$_ the almost sure convergence. This cannot be correct, as $p_{n,\varepsilon}\to 0$ for each positive $\varepsilon$ is equivalent to the convergence in probability. Here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/convergence-in-probability-vs-almost-sure-convergence is a discussion on the difference between the two modes of convergence.

Comment: Yes I see now. Thanks! I'll leave it anyway.

Comment: Hey, sorry for some late question. The almost sure criteria could be summarized as $$\exists N\in\mathbb{N}, \forall n\geq N:p_{n,\epsilon}=0 \, ,$$ whereas I only have the weak condition $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} p_{n,\epsilon} = 0\, ,$$ right?